# Importing Output from Linux mpstat to Calculate Aggregate and Per-CPU Averages, Creating Tables and Graphs

Tags: import, list-manipulation

I'm a Mathematica noob, running a trial version for the moment, but have run into the wall trying to handle this in Excel and am looking for other options.

While running a benchmark application I'm gathering output from the Linux command "mpstat -P ALL 1" and exporting it to a CSV.  The data is as follows:

```
Time, CPU, %usr, %nice, %sys, %iowait, %irq, %soft, %steal, %guest, %gnice, %idle 
10:11:04 AM, all, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 100.00
10:11:04 AM, 0, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 100.00
10:11:04 AM, 1, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 100.00
10:11:04 AM, 2, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 100.00
...
more interesting data in the middle
...
11:18:55 AM, 12, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 100.00
11:18:55 AM, 13, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 100.00
11:18:55 AM, 14, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 100.00
11:18:55 AM, 15, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 100.00
```

There are 21 unique tests in the benchmark which are clearly visible when each sample with "CPU = all" is graphed.  (The Y axis is calculated as (100 - %idle).

[image: Excel Graph of "ALL" CPU utilization over Time]

What I need to do is the following:

- Separate the idle periods from the periods when the benchmark is running. (There are short idle periods before testing starts, in-between each test, and an idle period after all tests are complete.)  This is the part that gives me the biggest problem since the number of idle samples between tests is not entirely predictable.
- For each period when the performance test is running, find the average CPU utilization for each CPU (0, 1, 2, ..., 14, 15, all).
- Create a table that indicates the test name (e.g. Test 1, Test 2, etc.) and the average CPU utilization for each CPU sampled.

> ```
> +--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+ 
> |  Test  | CPU ALL | CPU 0 | CPU 1 | CPU 2 | CPU 3 | 
> +--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+ 
> | Test A |   30%   |  25%  |  35%  |  24%  |  36%  |
> +--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
> | Test B |   25%   |  20%  |  31%  |  24%  |  30%  |
> +--------+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+ 
> ...
> ```

The full data source can be found here: [mpstat.zip](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17517087/mpstat.zip)

Answer (score 1):

First, import the data:

```
data = Import[SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"]];
```

The first line is just the column descriptions, so remove it:

```
data = data[[2 ;; All]];
```

Each successive 17 elements is the CPU usage for CPU "all, 0, 1, ..., 15", so let's separate them by CPU:

```
{all, zero, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten,
    eleven, twelve, thirteen, fourteen, fifteen} = 
  Transpose[Partition[data, 17]];
```

Now let's plot $100-\text{idle}$ for the `all` partition:

```
allCPUtotal = 100 - all[[All, -1]];
ListLinePlot[allCPUtotal, AspectRatio -> 0.3, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

There are 21 groups of tests. Let's separate them by first applying `Unitize` with a threshold of $1\text{%}$, use `Split` to group them into chunks, and apply `Length` to the chunks.

```
bands = Length /@ Split[Unitize[allCPUtotal, 1]]
```

Output is

```
{17, 183, 10, 181, 11, 182, 10, 183, 10, 182, 10, 182, 11, 182, 10, \
182, 10, 183, 11, 182, 11, 182, 14, 182, 10, 181, 4, 1, 6, 182, 13, \
181, 11, 181, 10, 181, 11, 181, 2, 1, 8, 181, 10, 182, 11, 181, 22}
```

so it looks like each test lasts for 180 datapoints or so. Now we can use the previous indices to divide the data into chunks and apply `Mean`:

```
Grid[{Range[21], 
   Mean /@ DeleteCases[
     Table[allCPUtotal[[1 + Plus @@ bands[[1 ;; k]] ;; 
         Plus @@ bands[[1 ;; k + 1]]]], {k, 
       Length[list] - 1}], _?(Length[#] < 120 &)]}\[Transpose]]
```

which produces the output you want for each of the 21 tests on CPU "all":

$$\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 10.7827 \\
 2 & 13.5756 \\
 3 & 13.0415 \\
 4 & 12.4783 \\
 5 & 15.97 \\
 6 & 16.4924 \\
 7 & 17.9606 \\
 8 & 9.87423 \\
 9 & 10.2238 \\
 10 & 10.4999 \\
 11 & 11.7471 \\
 12 & 12.5709 \\
 13 & 34.8297 \\
 14 & 24.7665 \\
 15 & 3.16022 \\
 16 & 2.45746 \\
 17 & 3.37475 \\
 18 & 3.79895 \\
 19 & 4.82945 \\
 20 & 4.45 \\
 21 & 5.42917 \\
\end{array}
\right]$$

and you can simply modify the preceding to get the results for each individual CPU. Here's a way to do that for all 17 datasets in one shot. Partition everything and call it `chunk`:

```
chunk = Transpose[Partition[data, 17]];
```

Then get the busy times ($100-\text{idle}$):

```
hundredMinusIdle = 100 - chunk[[All, All, -1]];
```

Then just compute the average CPU use for all of the 17 partitions, and display it using `MatrixForm`:

```
Prepend[Transpose[
   Prepend[Table[
     Mean /@ DeleteCases[
       Table[hundredMinusIdle[[j, 
          1 + Plus @@ bands[[1 ;; k]] ;; 
           Plus @@ bands[[1 ;; k + 1]]]], {k, 
         Length[list] - 1}], _?(Length[#] < 120 &)], {j, 17}], 
    Range[21]]], Flatten@{"Test", "All", Range[0, 15]}] // MatrixForm
```

Here's a screenshot of the output:

[image]

Right click and open the image in a new tab to get it in readable resolution.

Comment: In v10 you could even run the mpstat call itself using `RunProcess`. You could also try importing the data with `SemanticImport`, which should pick up things like times and the column headers automatically. The resulting data, which is in the form of a `Dataset`, is also probably easier to process and get means etc. Those last two big chunks of code are kinda impenetrable, in my view, "write only code".